# ASP.NET custom role management

Tags: c#, asp.net, role

There is Role Management feature in ASP.NET
It works on local development machine.

For our project we need customers admin to be able to create new users and manage their roles.
So, basically same what aspnet_regsql.exe does.

Question is
Should we develop our own pages and forms or use some ready made tool?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need the [SqlRoleProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlroleprovider.aspx).

You can also plug in your own custom Role Provider (and Membership Provider). See [How to: Sample Role-Provider Implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/317sza4k(v=VS.90).aspx)

Comment: How was this the answer to the question?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and solved it by integrating the SecurityGuard NuGet package. It has pretty nice user interface and allows you to manage users as well as roles.

Just following the guide at the following link:
http://www.mvccentral.net/Story/Details/tools/kahanu/securityguard-nuget-package-for-asp-net-membership

Answer (score 0):

Here is a guide with code to doing the role manager UI: [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa530759(v=MSDN.10).aspx).

Have you seen [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy40ytx0.aspx) Web Admin tool?

It looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, of course i've seen that!
But "To access the Web Site Administration Tool, on the Website menu, click ASP.Net Configuration."

But this button is only available in VS.

Question is how to get the same menu when the site/project is up and running. So that client can add users / manage roles after development is over.

Will the same tool still be available, or should we write our own?

Answer (score 0):

> So that client can add users / manage roles after development is over.

Alex, I had exactly this problem on an application a couple of years ago and I found and adapted this sample:

[Microsoft ASP.NET 2.0 Member/Role Management with IIS, Part 2: Implementation](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478947.aspx)

There was a slight bug in the ToggleInRole_Click method that I had to tweak (I can give you my fix if you want) but apart from that it worked well.