# ASP.NET, Open LDAP role based security

Tags: asp.net, openldap, rbac

I have couple of applications developed in asp.net with authentication from Open LDAP. The applications are working fine and I am having no problem with authentication.

The main problem is to manage user roles and responsibilities and the requirements change quite frequently. Can any one suggest an open source framework to manage user roles or any other ways to manage user roles i.e. within open LDAP etc...

I have studied few commercial solutions like Visual Guard but am looking for open source.

Comment: Saqib, this sounds more like a processes and practices problem than coding problem per se.  You might have better success asking this over on http://serverfault.com - the server administration equivalent of Stackoverflow where this problem is almost certainly more commonly encountered.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement [custom Role provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fw7xh74.aspx) using [Novell's LDAP library for C#](http://www.novell.com/developer/ndk/ldap_libraries_for_c_sharp.html) to perform queries against directory.

[LDAP groups](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/access-control.html#Managing%20access%20with%20Groups) can be used as a backing store for roles.

Comment: My Open LDAP is currently being used by many applications and creating user groups for all the applications (for roles) looks quite hard to manage.

Comment: You are not forced to use LDAP groups with custom provider. Plain/XML files or database are easy to use. Check these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728976/asp-net-custom-role-management http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760871/sample-c-code-to-manage-roles-with-roles-provider