# Authenticate based off LDAP Group in Webconfig

Tags: asp.net, ldap, web-config, windows-authentication, asp.net-roles

The setup is as follows:

I have an AD Security Group "DOMAIN\MYGROUP" populated with users.
I have an LDAP eDir Group "DOMAIN\MYGROUP-Approvers" populated with admins for the group.

In my webconfig I can use the **AD Security Group** to authenticate and **it works**

```
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow roles="DOMAIN\MYGROUP"/>
    <deny users="*"/>        
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

However using the **LDAP Group** to authenticate **does not work.**

```
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow roles="DOMAIN\MYGROUP-Approvers"/>
    <deny users="*"/>        
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

How can I configure my webconfig to work for LDAP Groups the same way it works for AD Security Groups?

Thanks!

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but what is an eDir group?

Comment: A group (in my case MYGROUP-Approvers) within the LDAP eDirectory.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely need to create a [custom role provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4552495/asp-net-open-ldap-role-based-security) that could return eDir roles. Go to MSDN for more information. Another try might be to modify [ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726837/user-group-and-role-management-in-net-with-active-directory).

For a quick and dirty solution you can also try to overwrite [Application_PostAuthenticateRequest](https://brockallen.com/2013/01/17/adding-custom-roles-to-windows-roles-in-asp-net-using-claims/) and add eDir roles to AD roles.